# Limiting memory of V8 Context

Tags: v8

I have a script server that runs arbitrary java script code on our servers.  At any given time multiple scripts can be running and I would like to prevent one misbehaving script from eating up all the ram on the machine.   I could do this by having each script run in its own process and have an off the shelf monitoring tool monitor the ram usage of each process, killing and restarting the ones that get out of hand.  I don't want to do this because I would like to avoid the cost of restart the binary every time one of these scripts goes crazy.  Is there a way in v8 to set a per context/isolate memory limit that I can use to sandbox the running scripts?

Answer (score 1):

It should be easy to do now

- `context.EstimatedSize()` to get estimated size of the context
- `isolate.TerminateExecution()` when context goes out of acceptable memory/cpu usage/whatever

in order to get access if there is an infinite loop(or something else blocking, like high cpu calculation) I think you could use `isolate.RequestInterrupt()`

Comment: Does not look like that works: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/42ba9ef7242dad4bef42464c50ea9c526ee6f005/src/api.cc#L6696

Answer (score 1):

A single process can run multiple isolates, if you have a 1 isolate to 1 context ratio you can easily

1. restrict memory usage per isolate
2. get heap stats

See some examples in this commit:

https://github.com/discourse/mini_racer/commit/f7ec907547e9a6ea888b2587e4edee3766752dd3

In particular you have:

```
v8::HeapStatistics stats;
isolate->GetHeapStatistics(&stats);
```

There are also fancy features like memory allocation callbacks you can use.

Answer (score 0):

This is not reliably possible.
All JavaScript contexts by this process share the same object heap.

WebKit/Chromium tries some stuff to disable contexts after context OOMs.
http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/bindings/v8/V8Proxy.cpp&exact_package=chromium&q=V8Proxy&type=cs&l=361

Sources:

- http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/heap.h?r=11125&spec=svn11125#280
- http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40521
- http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=81227